# alert message use javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

hello I need my result to appear in an alert that says correct I have tried many codes and I have had a result, well what I want is that if I say the correct word it tells me in a correct message and it has a button that says next there is I leave my code I hope your help

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (typeof speechSynthesis == 'undefined' || 
      typeof webkitSpeechRecognition == 'undefined')
    return alert('Only Chrome browser is supported');

var $success = new Audio('correct.mp3');
var $tada = new Audio('tada.mp3');  

var $button = document.querySelector('#page-card #button'); 
var $image = document.querySelector('#page-card #image');
var $word = document.querySelector('#page-card #word');
var $translate = document.querySelector('#page-card #translate');
var $answer = document.querySelector('#page-card #answer');

$image.addEventListener('click', e => speakText($word.textContent));
            
var voice;
loadVoices();
if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) 
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => loadVoices();   


var group, cardNo;
document.querySelectorAll('#page-selector .group').forEach(function ($e) {
    $e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        group = e.target.id;
        togglePage();
        showCard(0);
    });
});

document.querySelectorAll('#page-card #option > *[ref]').forEach(function ($e) {

    $e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        this.toggleAttribute('pushed');
        const $div = document.querySelector('#page-card #' + this.getAttribute('ref'));
        console.log(this.getAttribute('ref'), $div);    
        $div.style.visibility = $div.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    });
});


function speakText(text) {
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    utterance.voice = voice;
    utterance.rate = 0.8;
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
};

function loadVoices () {
    voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
        .find((e, i) => i > 0 && e.lang.indexOf('en') == 0 && (e.lang.indexOf('US') != -1 || e.lang.indexOf('UK') != -1 || e.lang.indexOf('GB') != -1));
         
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then (function (stream) {
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = false;
    recognition.lang = 'en';
    
    function start() {
        recognition.start();
        $button.setAttribute('hold', true);
    }
    
    function stop () {
        recognition.stop();
        $button.removeAttribute('hold');            
    }

    $button.addEventListener('mousedown', start);
    $button.addEventListener('touchstart', start);

    $button.addEventListener('mouseup', stop);
    $button.addEventListener('touchend', stop);
    
    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var answer = event.results[0][0].transcript.toLowerCase();
        $answer.innerHTML = answer;
        if (answer == data[group][cardNo].word || data[group][cardNo].alt && data[group][cardNo].alt.indexOf(answer) != -1) {
            if (cardNo < data[group].length - 1) {
                $success.play();
                showCard(cardNo + 1);
            } else {
                $tada.play();
                togglePage();
            }   
        }
    }
    recognition.onerror = err => $error.innerHTML = err.message;
    
}).catch((err) => alert(err.message));


function showCard(no) {
    cardNo = no;
    var curr = data[group][cardNo];
    $image.style.backgroundImage = `url('images/${group}/${curr.word}.jpg')`;
    $word.innerHTML = curr.word;
    $translate.innerHTML = curr.translate;
    $answer.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
}

function togglePage() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.page').forEach($e => $e.toggleAttribute('current'));
}
```

});

Comment: Please always include all the relevant code in your question (HTML, CSS as well as the JavaScript). That way we can see what you are dealing with and present a working solution.

Comment: Also (FYI), while it is legal to name a variable that starts with `$`, that is almost always a convention for a variable that holds an object reference returned by the use of a library, such as JQuery.  When you prefix your variables with that, it will make others think you are using JQuery, when (in this case), you are not.

Comment: And, what elements do you think have `pushed` and `ref` attributes? Are you using React?